# Run multiple REST API queries for single page at a time

Tags: html, rest

Is it possible to run multiple REST API queries for single page at a time?
I have a HTML page, it executes three REST API queries on page load, but I get results for only last query.
Are there any limitations?

Comment: I think best practice should be, give your example in code, so people can comment on in better way. Normally there is no limitation on rest api queries.

Answer (score 1):

You're not limited to a single query. You can check the browser's debugger to determine all the queries taking place. Also, can place breakpoints in the debugger to examine the flow of your code, which will help explain why you're seeing a single output. 
Also, sharing the page code would help determine the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no limit for such as requests or anything... You have to be sure to not confuse two API's. Keeping them different objects/scope, different variables etc. But don't forget, it's ok to keep them in same object/scope, if you are not use in same time...